# JSON Sorting output

Tags: javascript, json

#### I need to filter JSON Output

This is the array I read from...

```
{
  "AppointmentList":[{
    "Code":"10",
    "Index":"2000",
    "ResourceType":"1010",
    "ResourceId":"J",
    "ResourceName":"Jesper",
    "Active":true,
    "Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
    "PunchIn":"07:30",
    "PunchOut":"16:00",
    "BreakStart1":"09:00",
    "BreakEnd1":"09:15",
    "BreakStart2":"11:30",
    "BreakEnd2":"12:00",
    "BreakStart3":"14:00",
    "BreakEnd3":"14:15",
    "AppointmentList":[{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
    "StartTime":"07:00",
    "EndTime":"07:45",
    "OrderNo":19283},
      {"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
      "StartTime":"07:45",
      "EndTime":"15:30",
      "OrderNo":332211}],
      "AbsenceList":[]
},
    "Code":"101",
    "Index":"2000",
    "ResourceType":"1010",
    "ResourceId":"G",
    "ResourceName":"Gunner",
    "Active":true,
    "Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
    "PunchIn":"07:30",
    "PunchOut":"16:00",
    "BreakStart1":"09:00",
    "BreakEnd1":"09:15",
    "BreakStart2":"11:30",
    "BreakEnd2":"12:00",
    "BreakStart3":"14:00",
    "BreakEnd3":"14:15",
    "AppointmentList":[{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
    "StartTime":"07:00",
    "EndTime":"07:45",
    "OrderNo":19283},
      {"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z",
      "StartTime":"07:45",
      "EndTime":"15:30",
      "OrderNo":112233}],
      "AbsenceList":[]
```

I got this now:

```
let orders = Data.AppointmentList.flatMap(a => a.AppointmentList).map(a => a.OrderNo);
console.log(orders.join(', '));
```

I only need output OrderNo, where Code = "101", and OrderNo != 0

So
AppointmentList.Code === "101"
AppointmentList.AppointmentList.OrderNo != 0

#### Output should be = 112233

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks, but i try that... I don't know how :(

Comment: Fix your JSON it's invalid.

Comment: {"AppointmentList":[{"Code":"10","Index":"2000","ResourceType":"1010","ResourceId":"J","ResourceName":"Jesper","Active":true,"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","PunchIn":"07:30","PunchOut":"16:00","BreakStart1":"09:00","BreakEnd1":"09:15","BreakStart2":"11:30","BreakEnd2":"12:00","BreakStart3":"14:00","BreakEnd3":"14:15","AppointmentList":[{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","StartTime":"07:00","EndTime":"07:45","OrderNo":19283},{"Date":"2019-05-06T00:00:00Z","StartTime":"07:45","EndTime":"15:30","OrderNo":19246}],"AbsenceList":[]},

Comment: It's some of the Data

Comment: It's not invalid, it's working...

Answer (score 0):

Always try to share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That said, here is how you can achieve it using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let Data = {
  "AppointmentList": [
    {
      "Code": "10",
      "AppointmentList": [
        {
          "OrderNo": 19283
        },
        {
          "OrderNo": 332211
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Code": "101",
      "AppointmentList": [
        {
          "OrderNo": 19283
        },
        {
          "OrderNo": 112233
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let orders = Data.AppointmentList
                   .filter(a => a.Code === "101") 
                   .flatMap(a => a.AppointmentList)
                   .filter(a => a.OrderNo !== 0);

let orderNos = orders.map(a => a.OrderNo);
console.log(orderNos)
```